# What are reasons for which a less qualified person is hired as a lecturer?

Tags: mathematics, faculty-application, lecturer, adjunct-faculty

I have worked as an adjunct at my University for 12 years, and I got my PhD (in mathematics) a few years ago. My goal, after getting my PhD, was to continue being an adjunct in my University until a Lecturer position opens up and apply for it. Recently, a Lecturer position opened up and I applied for it. I have taught pretty much my entire Universities curriculum, including all the upper level courses which are never taught by any other adjuncts. However, I was not accepted for this position.

The person who was accepted, satisfies the following properties:

- Has taught less than 1/3 of all the courses that I taught, at my University.
- Did not teach at my University for the past 5 years, and only recently taught one class the recent semester when the Lecturer position opened up.
- Only taught lower level courses.
- Does not have a PhD (though is currently working on one).

Furthermore, the job application for this Lecturer position, clearly stated, that preference would be given to the individual who has a vast array of teaching experience of courses offered in the University.

My question is:

Which reasons exist to hire the less qualified person? If someone is more qualified than I am, then surly they should get the position. But based on this person's career history, they were not more qualified. And if I believe that an incorrect decision was made, which hurts me, and is contrary to the job description, what actions can I take?

Comment: As it was, your question was much to dependent on personal factors and thus likely to be closed. I tried to edit it to make it more general.

Comment: See also: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/195976/what-are-the-main-differences-that-separate-applicants-who-get-academic-jobs-ove

Comment: Two things: (a) for career-centric positions, qualifications are not seen as absolute but in proportion to career age; (b) if you have 12 years of teaching experience you may well be seen as overqualified for an entry-level teaching position.

Comment: @xLeitix The person who got the Lecturer job also has 12 years of teaching experience. But their teaching experience is low level intro-level math. So on the basis of working-age, we have been both working at this for the same amount of time.

Comment: *But their teaching experience is low level intro-level math.* -- Depending on the department's needs, this may be more important than some of the seemingly stronger qualifications you have. In fact, this was my first thought when I read your question yesterday.

Comment: @AxBy My feedback is to recommend you ask the people who actually were involved in the process and are willing to talk to you. Anyone can make up stories from guesses, but how do these actually help you?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro This is a good point, and this is what I thought of also, but the job application said, "preference would be given to the candidate that a vast array of courses offered in the department". If the job description said something else, then your suggestion would be applicable, but it is contrary to the job application.

Comment: @BryanKrause The problem is, those people are not willing to talk about it. Only some faculty members (who were not directly on the hiring committee, and can offer their views to them) can tell me their thoughts on the matter. How do you suggest to find this information out?

Comment: @AxBy Then I think it's probably not worth your effort to find it out, and if you want a different job you should apply to different jobs. You'll notice the pattern here is not very productive: people offer their guesses, you tell them why their guesses are wrong. That's why the question is closed as "strongly depending on individual factors".

Answer (score 3):

There could be plenty of reasons, which might be summarized as "life isn't fair".

- It might be that the other person really had some key skill or some certain certification that you don't know about (eg some teaching certificate, a gender-competence certificate)
- Nepotism might be involved in some way
- Somebody might have had some bias
- age (thanks to the commenters!)

etc...
Most likely, you will never know.

While it is good to always remember to be fair, unfortunately, there are many unfair things and lucky things going on in Academia.

Comment: add age to that list.  Moreover, there is little fear by admin of “loosing” the OP since they have been there for so long.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Absolutely! As an adjunct, I attended a departmental faculty meeting where it was explicitly stated that they were looking for a young person for the job. Despite the position being in a state university in the US.

Comment: It's always easier for a newcomer to seem shiny, fresh and exciting, and destined for great things; in comparison to the person who's been around for a long time and therefore seems unremarkable.

Comment: @avid This new person has actually taught at this University at the same starting year as me, and is older, but they took a long break until returning back and getting a position.

Comment: @AxBy I am afraid you are overdue to let this one go. You have been an adjunct for over a decade, if the faculty *wanted* to bring you on full-time somebody would have made it happen by now.

Comment: @xLeitix Perhaps, that is how it works in other Universities, but in my University there are other departments that approve funding, ect, and the hiring decision consists of people outside the mathematics department. The faculty members personally told me (including the former chair) that they wanted to make me a Lecturer, but they alone do not have that ability. Furthermore, the person who got the Lecturer position has been also an adjunct for over a decade as well, as long as I have.

Comment: @AxBy  it's your decision to make. Personally I would have stopped buying the "sorry, nothing I can do" argument years ago.

Comment: @xLeitix How do you know that the "Nothing I can do" argument is not actually correct? Universities are structured differently. At my University, the faculty members cannot simply elect new faculty members without approval from other departments. Administration probably takes priority over the math faculty.

Comment: Also consider cost: maybe there's some centrally-negotiated pay policy that says a lecturer with a PhD and lots of teaching experience has to be paid more, and the department only has the budget for a lecturer with no PhD and little teaching experience.

Comment: @DanielHatton Good observation, but in this University all Lecturers get paid the same.